# Reactive Cocoa Validation

Tags: swift, mvvm, reactive-cocoa

How can I validate a form after a RAC Command or a button click? I have this somewhere in my View Model

```
self.executeLoginRacCommand = RACCommand(enabled: activateButtonSignal, signalBlock: { (any : AnyObject!) -> RACSignal! in

            return self.executeLoginAPI()
        })

//My question is here, how can I display an alert to my view controller saying may email is invalid.
//MARK: - Execute Login API
    private func executeLoginAPI() -> RACSignal {
        if self.isEmailValid(self.email) {
            return self.signInServices.signInAPIService.signInAPISignal(self.email, password: self.password)
        } else {
            self.errorMessage = "Please insert a valid email"
            return RACSignal.empty()
        }
    }

//MARK: -  Is Email Valid
    func isEmailValid(email: String) -> Bool {
        let emailRegEx = "^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$"

        let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
        return emailTest.evaluateWithObject(email)
    }
```

I access it in my View Controller like this:

```
 self.signInButton.rac_command = self.signInViewModel.executeLoginRacCommand
```

Can you please suggest a good way of validating an invalid email and display alert after a button click? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you run a search for 'validate email' for yourself?

Comment: Yes, I have googled it a lot and cannot find an answer. I have try to change my code. And unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In your `else` branch, you are returning an empty RACSignal. 
Instead, return the a RACSignal that sends the error (`RACSignal.error(<the error>)`).

In your ViewController, you can subscribe to the `errors` property of `self.executeLoginRacCommand` and display the error to the user.